# Overriding mouse over behaviour in WPF combo box

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, wpf-controls

When the list is dropped down an the mouse hovers over an item in the drop-down list, the item becomes highlighted but the selected value shown in the text box does not change unless the item is clicked. I am looking for a way to modify the mouse over behavior in a control that inherits from ComboBox. I tried overriding function like `OnMouseEnter` & `OnMouseMove` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by overriding OnMouseMove.  The [OriginalSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) property of the MouseEventArgs will give you the element directly under the mouse.  You can use [ContainerFromElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346420.aspx) to get the ComboBoxItem that contains that element and then [ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.itemfromcontainer.aspx) to get the item to select:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    var container = ContainerFromElement((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
    if (container != null)
    {
        SelectedItem = ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(container);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the same issue in my code, hopefull that it could be usefull for someone else, or just a steps toward a full xaml solution.

I followed the Quartermeister's solution. But In my opinion, the need subclassing ComboBox is a design weakness (because this is done just for handling the MouseOver event). Because I need just for a different behaviour of the MouseOver event, I implemented just the method which handles MouseOver events in the class attached to XAML file.

First of all, I used the [EventSetter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx) class, which subclass the Setter class and it's specific for Events. So EventSetter can be used to decorate FrameworkElements as we usually do with Setter.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="_updateModel"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

In this way, every ComboBoxItem calls _updateModel when the mouse hovers it.

My implementation of _updateModel is quite straight, it's based strongly on the work of Quartermeister:

```
private void _updateModel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject src = e.Source as DependencyObject;
    ComboBoxItem cbi = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(src) as ComboBoxItem;
    while ((cbi == null) && (src!=null))
    {
        src = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(src);
        cbi = src as ComboBoxItem;
    }
    if (cbi != null)
    {
        ComboBox cb = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(cbi) as ComboBox;
        if (cb != null)
        {
            var container = cb.ContainerFromElement((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
            if (container != null)
            {
                cb.SelectedItem = cb.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(container);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other ways to solve the same issues can use [blend's behaviors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/2009/09/25/blend-behaviors.aspx)
for reasons that aren't worth to explain here, i couldn't use that behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead create your own control using a TextBlock, a ToggleButton with an arrow and a ListBox. Show the Listbox when the ToggleButton is checked. When user do mouse over a listboxitem, change the text in the Textbox and update some property for selected item or fire an event.